# C# calculating rent of room based on discount list

Tags: c#

I am trying to calculate room rent based on disount table. 
Problem statement: A company offers subsidized stay for its employees in one of its own guest house. The discount scheme is

- 50% off for first 2 days stay
- 25% off for next 2 days stay
- 15% off for next 2 days stay
- 0% off for stay beyond 6 days

The issue here is my calculations are always wrong. For example if an employee has already stayed in the guest house for 4 days and is now requesting 3 more days to stay, the rent should be calculated for 1 day with 0% discount. Similarly, if an employee has already stayed there for 2 days and is now requesting 5 more days to stay he should be charged 2 days with 25% discount, 2 days with 15% discount and 1 day with 0% discount. I hope this makes the problem clear.

Here is the program structure:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<ExemptionDetails> exemptionDetailsList = new List<ExemptionDetails>();

        exemptionDetailsList.Add(new ExemptionDetails{ExemptionTo = 2, ExemptionPercentage = 50});//First 2 Days, 50% off
        exemptionDetailsList.Add(new ExemptionDetails{ExemptionTo = 2, ExemptionPercentage = 25});//Next 2 Days, 25% off
        exemptionDetailsList.Add(new ExemptionDetails{ExemptionTo = 2, ExemptionPercentage = 15});//Next 2 Days, 15% off
        //No reimbursement for more than 6 days

        var perDayRent = 2000.00M;//per day rent of the room
        var daysAvailedInPast = 2;//has already availed 2 days discount
        var daysAppyingNow = 5;//need to calculate the rent of 5 days based on discount scheme
        var calculatedRent = 0.00M
        foreach (var item in exemptionDetailsList)
        {
            //I have tried a lot of options here but all of them failed. Need to calculate the rent for 5 days according to the list above.
        }

        Console.WriteLine(calculatedRent);//should give result: 8400
    }
}

public class ExemptionDetails
{
    public int ExemptionTo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int ExemptionPercentage
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, inside your loop you could simply decrease the days `daysApplyingNow -=    item.ExemptionTo` and then `calculatedRent += item.ExemptionTo * perDayRent; ` Break the loop if daysApplyingNow goes below zero. Watch out for corner case when remaining days are less then discount days. Try it out - and pls. update the code with your effort :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<ExemptionDetails> exemptionDetailsList = new List<ExemptionDetails>();

        exemptionDetailsList.Add(new ExemptionDetails { ExemptionTo = 2, ExemptionPercentage = 50 });//First 2 Days, 50% off
        exemptionDetailsList.Add(new ExemptionDetails { ExemptionTo = 2, ExemptionPercentage = 25 });//Next 2 Days, 25% off
        exemptionDetailsList.Add(new ExemptionDetails { ExemptionTo = 2, ExemptionPercentage = 15 });//Next 2 Days, 15% off
                                                                                                     //No reimbursement for more than 6 days

        var perDayRent = 2000.00M;//per day rent of the room
        var daysAvailedInPast = 3;//has already availed 2 days discount
        var daysAppyingNow = 5;//need to calculate the rent of 5 days based on discount scheme
        var calculatedRent = 0.00M;
        var daysRemain =  daysAppyingNow;
        foreach (var item in exemptionDetailsList)
        {  if (daysAvailedInPast - item.ExemptionTo >= 0)
            {
                daysAvailedInPast = daysAvailedInPast - item.ExemptionTo;
                continue;
            }

                if (daysRemain > 0)
            {
                if (item.ExemptionTo <= daysRemain) {
                    calculatedRent += ((perDayRent * (100-item.ExemptionPercentage)) / 100) * (item.ExemptionTo - daysAvailedInPast);
                    daysRemain = daysRemain - (item.ExemptionTo - daysAvailedInPast);
                }
                else {
                    calculatedRent += ((perDayRent * (100-item.ExemptionPercentage)) / 100) * daysRemain;
                    daysRemain = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
            daysAvailedInPast = 0;
        }
        if(daysRemain > 0)
        {
            calculatedRent += perDayRent * daysRemain;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(calculatedRent);//should give result: 8400
    }
}

public class ExemptionDetails
{
    public int ExemptionTo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int ExemptionPercentage
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also not giving correct result. If I change "daysAvailedInPast" to 1 the result should be 7400 whereas the above code gives 2500 and if I change "daysAvailedInPast" to 3 the result should be 8900 whereas the above code gives 3200

Comment: Updated the code, check now. It should work for all cases.